# Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, jcenter

While importing existing adroid project i got below exception.

```
 Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden.
```

problem occurred configuring root project 'sample'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1.
> Required by:
> project :
> > Could not resolve org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/2.6.1/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-2.6.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonarsource/scanner/gradle/sonarqube-gradle-plugin/2.6.1/sonarqube-gradle-plugin-2.6.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:1.2.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jre8/1.2.0/kotlin-stdlib-jre8-1.2.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:5.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm:5.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.1/asm-5.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.1/asm-5.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:5.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.1/asm-analysis-5.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-analysis/5.1/asm-analysis-5.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.1/asm-commons-5.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.1/asm-commons-5.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:5.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-util:5.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/5.1/asm-util-5.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-util/5.1/asm-util-5.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:4.9.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/jopt-simple/jopt-simple/4.9/jopt-simple-4.9.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.3.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.3.3.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/5.3.3/proguard-gradle-5.3.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/proguard/proguard-gradle/5.3.3/proguard-gradle-5.3.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01
> > Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/auto/value/auto-value/1.5.2/auto-value-1.5.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:22.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:common:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:22.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/22.0/guava-22.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/guava/guava/22.0/guava-22.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01 > com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:0.1.0
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:tracker:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/3.4.0/protobuf-java-3.4.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01
> > Could not resolve com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java-util:3.4.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.4.0/protobuf-java-util-3.4.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java-util/3.4.0/protobuf-java-util-3.4.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.2.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:bundletool:0.1.0-alpha01
> > Could not resolve com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.1.2.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.2/error_prone_annotations-2.1.2.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/errorprone/error_prone_annotations/2.1.2/error_prone_annotations-2.1.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javawriter/2.5.0/javawriter-2.5.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.56.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.56/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.56.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.56/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.1/asm-tree-5.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.1/asm-tree-5.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve it.unimi.dsi:fastutil:7.2.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/7.2.0/fastutil-7.2.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/json-simple/json-simple/1.1/json-simple-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle-api:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdk-common:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.2.0/kotlin-reflect-1.2.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.3.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/antlr/antlr4/4.5.3/antlr4-4.5.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.googlecode.juniversalchardet:juniversalchardet:1.0.3.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/juniversalchardet-1.0.3.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.squareup:javapoet:1.8.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/javapoet/1.8.0/javapoet-1.8.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.databinding:compilerCommon:3.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.analytics-library:shared:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.7/gson-2.7.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.12.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.12/commons-compress-1.12.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.6/httpclient-4.2.6.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.6/httpclient-4.2.6.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.1/httpmime-4.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:26.1.4
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/net/sf/kxml/kxml2/2.3.0/kxml2-2.3.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/annotations/13.0/annotations-13.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.sun.activation:javax.activation:1.2.0.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/javax.activation-1.2.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
> Could not resolve com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
> Required by:
> project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.4
> > Could not resolve com.google.jimfs:jimfs:1.1.
> > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/jimfs/jimfs/1.1/jimfs-1.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

How to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed an expected behavior as JCenter is not available over '**http**'. Here is the [announcement](https://jfrog.com/blog/secure-jcenter-with-https/). Please update the URL to https.

Comment: in android folder change build.gradle subsection buildscript.repositories.jcenter() url protocol from http to https